# Linphone IOS: SSL handshake failed : X509 - Certificate verification failed

Tags: ios, ssl, asterisk, linphone

While registering with my Asterisk Server, I get following error.
Can anybody tell me any workaround for this or how we can disable this ssl authentication from Linphone?

I found [Issue with TLS on Android - works on iPhone](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/linphone-developers/2013-11/msg00043.html) on Linphone-developers, and it says:

> ```
> To disable TLS server certificate verification, put this in linphonerc:
>
> [sip]
> verify_server_certs=0
> ```

But when i opened `linphonerc` file in iOS, I did not find `verify_server_certs` statement.

How do I register my device with my Asterisk server? How do I trust the Asterisk server's certifcate?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: "...I get following error." - What is the error?

Comment: "...to disable TLS server certificate verification..." - that's very bad advice. ***Don't*** follow it.

Comment: actually our server does not use certificates, so that is why have to disable from linphone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed the issue.

Its in my question actually.

To disable TLS server certificate verification, put this in linphonerc:

```
[sip]
verify_server_certs=0
```

Comment: Disabling certs verification dose not solve the problem. It creates possible security risk!